# Regex repeating letters

Tags: php, regex

How can I not allow a user to enter a word with repeating letters I already have the case for special characters?

I have tried this and it works for the special characters allowed in the text.

`^(?!.*([ \-])\1)\w[a-zA-z0-9 \-]*$`

3 My Address--

Will not work (--)

This is what I am trying to do for the letters `(?!.*([a-z])\1{4})` but it does not work it breaks the regex.

`(?!.*([ \-])\1)(?!.*([a-z])\1{4})\w[a-zA-z0-9 \-]*$`

It should prevent any repeating letters when they have been entered 4 times in a row for example this is for a address and as it stand I can enter.

`3 My Adddddddddd`

Comment: Honestly? I think this kind of validation is silly. How do you know there's no address like that anywhere in the world? Plus, there are much worse things people can put there, which you probably won't handle. If you want to validate addresses, how about using library for that? Or just pass whatever resembles an address and keep track manually.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You say you wish to validate words, but your regex permits spaces, suggesting you are validating strings, not words.  Your negative lookahead succeeds (the match fails) if the string contains `"  "` (two spaces), `" -"`, `"- "` or `"--"`. Considering that you say you want to prevent repeating *letters*, is that what you want? If the regex prevents (two) repeating letters, won't it prevent 4 or 100 as well? Please clarify by editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\2` backreference in the second lookahead, and mind using `[a-zA-Z]`, not `[a-zA-z]` in the consuming part:

```
^(?!.*([ -])\1)(?!.*([A-Za-z])\2{3})\w[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lwygsa/1).

The first capturing group is `([ -])` in the first lookahead, the second lookahead contains the second group, thus, `\2` is necessary.

As you want to filter out matches with at least 4 identical consecutive letters, you need `([A-Za-z])\2{3}`, not `{4}`.

Also, if you plan to match a digit at the beginning, consider replacing `\w` with `\d`.

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*([ -])\1)` - no two identical consecutive spaces or hyphens allowed in the string
- `(?!.*([A-Za-z])\2{3})`  - no four identical consecutive letters allowed in the string
- `\w` - the first char should be a letter, digit or `_`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*` - 0+ letters, digits, spaces or hyphens
- `$` - end of string.